# Miner seems to be stuck at receiving new blocks

Tags: mining-pools, litecoin, synchronization

I have two laptops cranking hashes for pooled mining. My Mac is set up correctly, and I see the (yay!!!) messages pretty often from the minerd.exe output.

However, the PC I have cranking never seems to get the (yay!!!) message. It keeps on doing hashes and then receiving the "Longpoll detected new block" message. I even downloaded the Litecoin-Qt wallet, let it synchronize with the system, and placed the Minerd and mining_proxy EXE files next to the Litecoin-Qt in hopes that it would be able to access the longest chain due to the effort of the Litecoin wallet's synching.

I followed the steps for a PC in *[Litecoin LTC mining guide, CPU](http://cryptocur.com/litecoin/litecoin-mining/)*.

How can I make it work?

Comment: is it because my PC is too slow that it doesnt solve the block before a new one is sent to it by the mining proxy? why is my MAC able to get the yay message every second/half a second?

Answer (score 1):

Try instead GPU mining with [Cgminer 3.7.2](https://github.com/ckolivas/cgminer) it has always worked well for me. Using CPU on a machine only, is really not worth it.